# Squid loads webpages incorrectly

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, squid

I'm trying to configure my VPS server to work as a simple HTTP proxy. I insatlled Squid 3.3.8 on CentOS 7.1.1503 and configured basic authentication with the `ncsa_auth`. Although the whole scheme seems to be working and i'm successfully connecting to my proxy from another PC, i'm now facing the issues with the webpage loading.
At example, when i'm trying to open http://mirrors.liquidweb.com/, webpage won't load correctly, Firefox just loads the half of it and then i see the message saying "Transferring data from liquidweb.com" for a while. Then it disappears without any result: webpage is still displayed half-loaded.
I did a little research about this problem, but the only solutions i could find were related to DNS-problems. It doesn't seem to be DNS-related problem, and adding `dns_v4_first on` option in my squid config hadn't made any result.
I want to especially point out that this is not a site or browser-related problem, because it showed up in all browsers i tried to open the website, and disabling the proxy in browser settings fixes the issue immediately.
It also doesn't seem to be the ISP-related problem since i can download the files through this proxy with ~50Mbps average speed. My `squid.conf` and the screenshot with the improperly loaded webpage are present below, thanks in advance for any guesses!

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic childred 5
auth_param basic realm liproxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours

#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
#acl Safe_ports port 21         # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
#acl Safe_ports port 70         # gopher
#acl Safe_ports port 210        # wais
#acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535     # unregistered ports
#acl Safe_ports port 280        # http-mgmt
#acl Safe_ports port 488        # gss-http
#acl Safe_ports port 591        # filemaker
#acl Safe_ports port 777        # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

#http_access deny to_localhost

acl ncsaauth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsaauth
dns_v4_first on

http_access deny all

http_port 0.0.0.0:3128

#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

`etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
*filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections 
# The --dport number is the same as in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access 
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

# Allow ping
#  note that blocking other types of icmp packets is considered a bad idea by some
#  remove -m icmp --icmp-type 8 from this line to allow all kinds of icmp:
#  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, first you say you want your squid setup as a transparent proxy (i.e. a proxy that works by "man in the middling" HTTP traffic), and then you're explicitly configuring your proxy in your web browser. Can you double check your terminology and also explicitly write out what you're trying to acheive? Also, it's not really possible to configure basic auth in a "transparent" setup

Comment: You can't use proxy authentication with interception / transparent mode. Ref: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy#Why_can.27t_I_use_authentication_together_with_interception_proxying.3F

Comment: This post might be relevant to your problem: https://squidproxy.wordpress.com/2007/06/05/thinsg-to-look-at-if-websites-are-hanging/

Comment: Sorry, looks like i really did messed up with the terminology. I thought that transparent proxy is a proxy that doesn't hide IP of it's user's and transfers the information about users IP in the headers.
Well, from the configuration file i posted above you can see that the only thing i want from squid to do is just act as a simple proxy. My config is pretty basic, i just configured basic authentication and that's all.
I've already edited my question, thanks for your correction.

Comment: This is a classic sign of a path MTU problem. What changes did you make to the firewall?

Comment: @MichaelHampton you mean firewall on the client side or the server side? On the Squid server i use iptables with settings that restrict any incoming connections from the Internet except for the ones that come to 22 and 3128 ports. I can also post my iptables config if it's necessary.

Comment: Most likely the server side, and you should post the complete firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, added config in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You copied your firewall from somewhere on the Internet, but apparently without fully reading and understanding it.

Consider this section:

```
# Allow ping
#  note that blocking other types of icmp packets is considered a bad idea by some
#  remove -m icmp --icmp-type 8 from this line to allow all kinds of icmp:
#  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

One reason that it is "a bad idea" to block all ICMP is that you are also blocking things like Fragmentation Needed responses, which are required for Path MTU discovery to work. And if that doesn't work, then you get hanging web pages, downloads that stall out, etc.

To resolve the problem, you should remove exactly what the comment says.

---

Better yet, dump this firewall entirely, and go back to the `firewalld` system which was included with CentOS 7. It will configure a proper firewall without all of these traps for the unwary.

Comment: Actually, i did read the description but didn't completely realise the meaning of this comment and didn't understood what the author meant to say with that "other types of icmp" and how blocking these types of the icmp may interfere with the server functioning.

I've read a very useful article posted by @Per von Zweigbergk and now i understand why i should allow Path MTU packets in my iptables config. I've just added the rule to my firewall and now my proxy works great!

Comment: I don't want to quit using iptables though, because i'm very used to it, it's simple and the only reason why it wasn't working properly this time was my own ignorance. 

Thanks a lot everyone for help, everything works fine now!

Comment: Sorry to say this, but looks like adding the rule didn't actually fix the issue. Yes, i was able to open a few websites for the several minutes correctly, but now it doesn't work again. Interesting thing is: i tcpdumped eth0 on the server side and didn't see any ICMP packets at all. I've read a bit about PMTU blackhole, and as i understood, it would affect all my interaction with the server, but i can tunnel my traffic through ssh and upload large files through SFTP without any issues. Maybe this is isn't a MTU-related problem at all?